# Is it possible to find out in command line if Local Area Connection 2 is connected?

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, vpn

I have [HideMyAss Pro VPN](http://hidemyass.com/vpn/).

I use a simple *.bat script to automate changing of the IP when needed. The file consists of the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -changeip  
sleep 30
```

The problem is that HMA sometimes takes 15 seconds to change ip, sometimes 20 seconds, sometimes more than 30 seconds, etc.

I'd like to get rid of `sleep 30` and instead exit the script when HMA finishes changing IP. Is there any way to do this?

If it's any help. I found out that if I run `ipconfig` while the IP change takes place, it returns `Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected` for Local Area Connection 2. I suppose it would suffice to know **if there's a command line command to find out if Local Area Connection 2 is connected** and somehow incorporate that into the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to check status of the network adapter. You can parse output of `ipconfig` (which is more accurately) but it's complicated.

This should do the trick.

```
set host=hidemyass.com
"C:\Program Files\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -changeip  
:wait
ping -n 1 %host% | find "Reply from" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto wait
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netsh` to check connection state of network card. Just use

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,*" %A in (`netsh interface show interface`) do @if "%D"=="Local Area Connection 2" set state=%B
```

and you will have the connection state captured in %state% variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question helped me i was seeking for the same thing "to change ip " i know there is always a delay but why not make it 1 min . As that would always work and waiting a bit longer wont matter if it works rite.